# Outlook Add In get Item after Property_Change Event

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

As the title suggest I am looking for a way to get the Item which fired the event.

I Bind Property_Change Event in the Application_ItemLoad event in which I have a object Item which it seems I can not use.

After the Property_Change is fired I need the Item which fired the event in order to call my function. Is there a way to get this? (I know I can get the current open Item via ActiveExplorer, but if the Items is modified in the main Window I get null).

Code:
ThisAddIn.cs

```
private Explorer _Explorer;
private List<WrapperItem> list = new List<WrapperItem>;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
   _Explorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
   _Explorer.SelectioNChange += _Explorer_SelectionChange;
}

void _Explorer_SelectionChange()
{
     list.Clear();
     foreach (MailItem mail in _Explorer.Selection)
     {
         list.Add(new WrapperItem(mail));
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting an event sink on a particular item, right? What is your code?

If you are tracking events from multiple objects, the rule of thumb is to create your own wrapper class that will contain a pointer to the object raising the event and implement the event handler in the same wrapper class. This way when an event fires, you will know which object raised it.

A sample wrapper (off the top of my head) can look something like

```
public class MailItemWrapper
{
  public MailItem item;
  public MailItemWrapper(MailItem OutlookItem)
  {
    item = OutlookItem;
    item.PropertyChange += new System.EventHandler(PropertyChangeHandler);
  }
  private PropertyChangeHandler(string Name)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Property named {0} changed on item {1}", name, item.Subject))
  }
}
```

Comment: sounds reasonable, could you provide a example or a link on how to use a wrapper class in this specific incident? (Im binding them currently over folders.items.propertchange

Comment: Also, never ever set event sinks on all items in a folder - you will kill your system. Either use MAPIFolder.Items events or only set up event sinks on the items in the Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection collection. Clear out the old items when Explorer.SelectionChange event fires and add the items in the Explorer.Selection to the list of items that you track.

Comment: it is a MAPIFolder.items.PropertyChange Event is this not correct? Thanks, but I know what a wrapper looks like, how do I apply this wrapper to my folder items?

Comment: Create one wrapper for each item that you need to track. As I mentioned above, loop through all items in Explorer.Selection, create a wrapper for each item, add to a list. When Explorer.SelectionChange event fires, clear the list and add the new contents of Explorer.Selection.

Comment: im using this.Application.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange += ThisAddIn_SelectionChange; but this event is only thrown as long as I stand in the mail Items, if I move anywhere else

Comment: Do not use multiple dot notation - the object that raises the events must be stored in a global (class) variable to avoid being garbage collected. Store Application.ActiveExplorer in a class member, then set up the event handler.

Comment: Thank you I got it working. But somehow the PropertyChange Event gets raised 3 Times if I update an Item in Outlook and then in the code.

Comment: The tip with garbage Collector just saved me another big search thank you =)

Comment: Also keep in mind that a single change can trigger multiple PropertyChange callbacks as other properties get updated because of the original change.

Comment: maybe you can help me again. I am getting a COMException Client operation unavaible sometimes, if I use Session.GetFolderFromID(entryID). This really happens just randomly. I can not reproduce it very well. It's outside from outlook and I am generating a new Application for this special use. Thanks a lot

Comment: I've done that now : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653772/comexception-a-client-operation-failed-outlook