# COMException: A client operation failed Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

in my Application I store different Folders EntryIDs (Emails, Contacts...) in order to select them at a later point.
The problem is, sometimes I get a COMException:

> *A client operation failed. (at
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass.GetFolderFromID(String
>   EntryIDFolder, Object EntryIDStore))*

Update:
I got another error message at the same operation (without modifying the code)

> *The messaging interface has returned an unknown error. If the problem persists, restart Outlook*

My code looks like:

```
       outlookApp.Session.GetFolderFromID(searchFolder);
```

OutlookApp is defined and declared that way:

```
 private ApplicationClass outlookApp;
try
        {
            outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            try
            {
                outlookApp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application")) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                outlookApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass;

            }
        }
```

My suggestion is, that this is somehow connected to shared folders, but I am not able to reproduce the error on a regular basis.
The Outlook is in Cache Mode. Exchange is throwing a lot of Sync Errors with Calendars, but I'm not working on them. 
I cannot reproduce the error on a test vm with the users mailbox. I tried repairing with the internal tool from office (it found errors), but this did not fix anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working in a networked environment, you will have errors. This is unavoidable. Your code must be prepared to handle errors like that.

Comment: The Outlook is in Cache Mode. Exchange is throwing a lot of Sync Errors with Calendars, but I'm not working on them. Can you advise how I can avoid this problem or handle this proberly?